# AttributeError module 'discord.client' has no attribute 'command'

Tags: python, discord.py

So I was following a Python Discord tutorial on creating a Discord bot. When I run the code, it said "AttributeError module 'discord.client' has no attribute 'command'" I tried using commands.command() it is nor giving any errors, but this time it is not working. Here is my code:

```
from discord import message
from discord import client
from discord.ext import commands



class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return
        
        if message.content == ("/id"): 
            await message.channel.send(message.channel.id)

        if message.content == (".read"):
            with open("database.txt", "r") as f:
                content = f.read()
            await message.channel.send(content)
   
    @client.command()
    @commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
    async def admin_only_commands(self, message):
        if message.author == self.user:
            return
        if message.content == ("/apply"):
            with open("database.txt", "a") as f:
                f.write(f"\n" + str(message.channel.id))
            await message.channel.send("Data stored successfully: " + str(message.channel.id))


       
        
      
            
client = MyClient()
client.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use commands.bot from `discord.ext`

```py
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import message

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", case_insensitive=True)

@bot.event
async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)

@bot.event
async def on_message(self, message):
        # don't respond to ourselves
        if message.author == self.user:
            return
        
        if message.content == ("/id"): 
            await message.channel.send(message.channel.id)

        if message.content == (".read"):
            with open("database.txt", "r") as f:
                content = f.read()
            await message.channel.send(content)
   
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def admin_only_commands(self, message):
    if message.author == self.user:
        return
    if message.content == ("/apply"):
       with open("database.txt", "a") as f:
           f.write(f"\n" + str(message.channel.id))
       await message.channel.send("Data stored successfully: " + str(message.channel.id))

bot.run(TOKEN)
```